# Testing LDAP Connections to Active Directory Server

Tags: testing, active-directory, ldap, openldap

I'm writing a Linux application that accesses a LDAP server (currently OpenLDAP).

I would like to also test the application with an Active Directory server since that might be used in production.

Is there any free demo or trial version from Microsoft that would allow me to run this test in a VM ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can download a [evaluation copy of Windows Server 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/trial-software.aspx).  You have 180 days to do your evaluation.  After you successfully install the Windows Server 2008 R2, you just click Windows button and type in "dcpromo".  It will launch a wizard and guide you setting up the domain controller (i.e. the LDAP server + KDC)